# List All Active AWS Resources Contributing to Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm learning AWS using my Free Tier Account. By mistake, I forgot to delete an EC2 Snapshot after creating it (during my learning process). It kept on running and by the time I saw the 85% free tier usage warning mail, the usage crossed 100%.

Now, I'm cautious and clean up resources after creating them. To avoid any such future mistake, I want to list my resources in all regions which are contributing towards billing.

I have already gone through the Tag Editor in Resource Group. But, it also lists a lot of other resources which are default and cannot be stopped such as Network ACLs, DHCP Option sets, and others. They are not contributing towards my usage (correct me if I'm wrong).

[image]

I simply want to list all Resources which are directly contributing to my bill. For example, my EC2 active instances, EBS storage, S3 buckets, Snapshots, and these resources from all regions.

I have gone through a lot of guides and answers on StackOverflow, but none of them helped finding what I'm looking.

Comment: I use the Billing Console and Cost Explorer to view this type of information. It only shows resources that contribute to costs. You can also [Track your AWS Free Tier usage - AWS Billing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/tracking-free-tier-usage.html).

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein for the suggestion. I keep tracking AWS Free Tier Usage. But some services are not included in Free Tier, and you're billed for it. In my case, I was billed for EFS. It was tough to find it, as the Billing Console listed it in the highest cost spend section after 2-3 days. During that 2-3 days, it was nearly impossible for me to find that I have an EFS resource active in N. Virginia region, as it is not my default region.